# send payment from one address to another from my website

Tags: bitcoind, payment

I want to send payment to bitcoin address weekly from my bitcoin address,I have tried blockchain api but can't seem to find an answer.Need help.

Comment: Any suggestion on what language or system to use? (javascript, node.js, wordpress, php, etc)

Comment: This question is little scarce on details. Would you like to eloborate more what kind of wallets and what kind of transactions you need to do?

Comment: Yeah,what I want is to send bitcoins to others,so I guess I need to send to their bitcoin address  and that too weekly,and I want to do it in PHP,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api

The api call to send is:

```
https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$main_password&second_password=$second_password&to=$address&amount=$amount&from=$from&shared=$shared&fee=$fee¬e=$note
```

In PHP, replace all the variables (they start with a $ in example up above) with your actual info. Some of the parameters in the url are optional so visit the page I linked to see which ones are optional. Keep the url as a string and feed it in to this:

```
$result = file_get_contents($the_url_you_just_made);
```

This should send a payment as soon as it runs, you may want to read the resulting string, it will contain the error message if anything goes wrong. The response is detailed on the link and you can try out URLs in browser as well, just type in GUID, amount, address, etc in the correct places.

Comment: Thanks boss,now that's what I wanted when asked for the question

Comment: How to make the API call in a dummy way i.e. in a sanbox manner just like PayPal ?